# Java obfuscation using Proguard before native-image?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Is there any benefit of using Proguard for obfuscating java app, before compiling it to the executable binary using Graalvm's native-image?

As far as I understand, Proguard is only obfuscating class/method/param names, which are anyway not present when compiled to binary (or maybe I'm wrong here)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using GraalVM Native Image instead of obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65531208/using-graalvm-native-image-instead-of-obfuscation)

Comment: Sort of. There it is written that for string obfuscation you should run obfuscator, but Proguard  seems not to do that. I wondered if there is anything else that it does, and which is not already covered by native-image.